# Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: asp.net-ajax, telerik, rad

Here is the scenario:

I have two dropdowns on the page. When you select an item in the first dropdown, second dropdown is populated. On the page is also Submit button & a reset button (with javascript code). All of these controls are inside Telerik RadAjaxPanel ( same as asp.net UpdatePanel). There is also a asp.net ajax ScriptManager on the page. Locally, on developer's machine when I click on the reset button, page resets just fine. when deployed on a QA machine, we get following error message.

Error message:

---

Exception information: 
    Exception type: IndexOutOfRangeException 
    Exception message: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://000.000.000.000:8080/PageName.aspx 
    Request path: /PageName.aspx 
    User host address: 000.000.0.00 
    User: department 
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: Forms 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 6 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform.DecryptData(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount, Byte[]& outputBuffer, Int32 outputOffset, PaddingMode paddingMode, Boolean fLast)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform.TransformFinalBlock(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
   at System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData(Boolean fEncrypt, Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length, IVType ivType, Boolean useValidationSymAlgo)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.DecryptStringWithIV(String s, IVType ivType)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

---

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks,

Salil

Comment: How are you "resetting" the page?  Are you doing a response.redirect to the current url?

Answer (score 0):

Use the telerik forums or support ticket system to submit the issue to them. Also test on a third machine to make sure that the QA machine is not with somewhat corrupted configuration.